# Very bad wireless performance

Tags: wifi, performance, iwlwifi

I'm struggling with very poor wireless performance on a Fedora 25 setup running kernel 4.8.15-300.fc25.x86_64.

When downloading anything via wget, I get like 5Kb/s, and downloads usually stop. If I happen to launch the following ping command in bash while trying to download, performance is fine (about 1Mb/s).

```
ping google.fr -i .05
```

As far as I tested, I can surf on internet with some 3-5 seconds lag between pages, which disappears if I use that ping command.

Wifi driver is iwlwifi, firmware is installed even if dmesg complains:

```
[    4.225476] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-24.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.225484] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-7265D-23.ucode failed with error -2
[    4.226742] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.361476.0 op_mode iwlmvm
```

According to bugzilla (see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1400269), this shoudln't be an issue.

I manage my own AP (TPLink EAP 110) where I tried to change channel, disabling 802.11n, changing channel width, nothing helps.

The laptop I have the wireless issues with also has a Win10 dualboot. Wifi performance on Win10 is normal.

I can imagine that at some point, the ping forces a keep alive or something (not a wireless specialist speaking).

I have no clue how to get around this. Any ideas please ?

Comment: It's nice to know that I am not the only one experiencing this issue.  I also have those same error messages in dmesg.  I am getting single- and double-digit kb speeds when I perform a dnf update.  I am running Fedora 25 on a System 76 Lemur with 16GB, and kernel 4.8.15-300.fc25.x86_64.  I think there may have been a bad driver update.

Comment: What wireless card do you have ? Also, can you check if fast pinging some ip like above resolves your speed issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well in my case, I've tried disabling 802.11n, tried other iwl-7265D firmwares. At the end of the day, disabling power management did the trick with `iwconfig wlan0 power off`.
Seems to be a big issue with intel cards and iwlwifi drivers.

Rendering this permanent is done by creating the following file in /etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/02-wlan-power

```
#!/bin/sh
IF=$1
STATUS=$2

IFACES=$(iwconfig 2> /dev/null | grep "802.11" | awk '{print $1}')
for iface in $IFACES; do
    if [ "${IF}" = "${iface}" ] && [ "${STATUS}" = "up" ]; then
        iwconfig ${iface} power off
        logger "${iface}: turning off powersave mode to prevent constant reconnections"
    fi
done
```

Don't forget to chmod 755 that file.
Rebooting should do the trick.

Comment: I tried iwconfig power off on my wireless adapter, and it didn't make any difference.  It's a fairly recent problem, within the last couple of weeks I think.

Comment: What's your iwconfig output after the command ? Also, do you have control over your wireless AP ?